# How to attach a PDF file in landscape format as panel format in Jasper Report?

Tags: java, pdf, jasper-reports, panel, landscape

I am working with Jasper Report to generate a PDF file wiht other pdf files as attachments.

I have a organisation chart as pdf file in landscape format and I want to attach it to the output pdf file in PANEL format.

How is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

It seems not to be possible to attach another .pdf file directly from within JasperReport. See http://jasperforge.org/plugins/espforum/view.php?group_id=102&forumid=103&topicid=30388 . The only way to do that is to use iText externally and modify/use the .pdf which you get from Jasper.